# Restore USB Stick after using it to install TrueNAS Core

Tags: debian, windows, usb, freebsd, bootable

Im facing a problem and, im running out of option.

I used a usb stick to install TrueNAS on old computer to make a home server, I downloaded the iso from TrueNAS website and used rufus to burn it on my usb stick.

after installing the NAS i wanted to use back the USB stick on my pc windows. but can't do nothing about.

I tried to formate it in fat32 via windows and Gparted, but i have the next error "device is in readonly"

i tried via cmd (diskpart) and linux

```
sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb
```

command to change the readonly but didnt worked. i also try to delete the table of partition with gparted and create a new one on the stick but not worked also.

Answer (score 0):

Write zeros over the whole device using dd with something like

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda
```

then start again with formatting and partitioning. Sometimes these things depend on the nature and quality of the usb.